# Axios does not return the error in the frontend

Tags: node.js, express, axios

I'm using Axios to consume an API on my **backend** with **the NODEJS + EXPRESS** ...

After this, I use Axios in my **frontend** with **ES6 + JAVASCRIPT ORIENTED TO OBJECTS** ...

What happens is the following, if I get through my backend in the API route, it returns me the error when it is to return, and returns me the date when it is to return ...

But in my **frontend**, the **axios catch does not work** **because** it **returns me inside my date error and does not change status and statusText**.

I would like to know why this happens, and fix on my **backend** into the **"date" attribute** it **returns me the result when there is no error**, and **when there is error it change the "status" and "statusText" attribute of the Axios response to the catch on the frontend will work** ..

**BACKEND CONTROLLER CODE (NODEJS CONSUME API):**

```
module.exports.consume = (app, req, res) => {
    // PARAMS && QUERYS
    const xsjs        = req.params.urn;
    const shoppingId  = req.query.Shop,
          periodOf    = req.query.PeriodOf,
          periodUntil = req.query.PeriodUntil,
          kpi         = req.query.Kpi,
          select      = req.query.Select;

    // API_DAO.JS (CLASS)
    const apiDAO = new app.models.apiDAO(xsjs, shoppingId, periodOf, periodUntil, kpi, select);
          apiDAO.getResponseAxios().then  ( response => res.json(response.data) )
                                   .catch ( error    => res.json({ ErrorStatus: error.response.status, ErrorText: error.response.statusText }) );
}
```

**AXIOS IN MY FRONTEND**

```
class Api {
    constructor(xsjs, shoppingId, periodOf, periodUntil, kpi, select){
        this.xsjs        = xsjs;
        this.shoppingId  = shoppingId;
        this.periodOf    = periodOf;
        this.periodUntil = periodUntil;
        this.kpi         = kpi;
        this.select      = select;
    }

    configAxios(){
        return axios.create({
            baseURL:             'http://localhost:3000/api/',
            method:              'GET',
            responseType:        'json',
            responseEncoding:    'utf8',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type':  "application/json",
                'Cache-Control': "no-cache",
            },
            params: {  
                Shop:       this.shoppingId,
                PeriodoDe:  this.periodOf,
                PeriodoAte: this.periodUntil,
                Kpi:        this.kpi,
                Select:     this.select
            }
        });
    }

    async consume(){ return await this.configAxios().get(`/${this.xsjs}?`); }
}
```

**Axios Error Response on the Frontend**

Note that it inserts within the date attribute the errors and does not change the status or statusText out of the date attribute. (This should be wrong, as there was an error in the API query on my backend)

[image: img1]
**Axios Response, when executed with Parameters and Query correctly**

[image: img2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is inside `.catch` callback. There was an error on your backend side but after catching it you send a normal JSON response with default `200` status code:

```
.catch(error => res.json({ ErrorStatus: error.response.status, ErrorText: error.response.statusText }) );
```

If you want your backend to respond with HTTP error you need to set HTTP status code in a different way:

```
.catch(error => res.status(error.response.status).send(error.response.statusText);
```